# Let $\sigma_k$ denote the action of the symmetric group on $k$-tensors. Are the maps $\sigma_k(s)$ linearly independent for $s \in \mathfrak S_k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products

The action is defined as follows

> The symmetric group $\mathfrak S_k$ acts on the left on the space $L = \bigotimes^k \mathbb C^n$ via the following representation
> $$ \sigma_k : \mathfrak S_k \rightarrow End(\otimes ^k \mathbb C^n) : s \mapsto \sigma_k(s)$$
> where $$ \sigma_k(s)(v_1\otimes\dots \otimes v_k) := v_{s^{-1}(1)} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{s^{-1}(k)}.$$

I'm trying to show that the algebras $\mathbb C \mathfrak S_k$ and $\mathcal A:=\text{Span } \sigma_k(\mathfrak S_k)$ are isomorphic as algebras. I've therefore defined a map

$$ \mathbb C \mathfrak S_k \rightarrow \mathcal A: \sum_{s \in \mathfrak S_k} \mu_ss \mapsto \sum_{s \in \mathfrak S_k} \mu_s \sigma_k(s)$$
and hope that this is actually an algebra isomorphism. This map is clearly surjective so it remains to prove that it is also injective. Therefore suppose that

$$ \sum_{s} \mu_s \sigma_k(s) = 0$$

and I want to show that $\sum_s \mu_s s =0$. That is, I'd like to show that $\mu_s = 0$ for all $s \in \mathfrak S_k$. That is, I'd like to show that the maps $\sigma_k(s)$ are linearly independent. How can I prove this ?

***Attempts*** :

Let $e_1,...,e_n$ denote a basis of $\mathbb C^n$. If $k \leq n$ then I can define $I = (1,...,k)$ and $e_1 \otimes ... \otimes e_k:= e_I \in L$ as well as $e_{s \cdot I}:= \sigma_k(s)e_I$. So we have
$$ \sum_{s} \mu_s \sigma_k(s) e_I = 0 \iff \sum_{s} \mu_s e_{s \cdot I} = 0.$$
In this case all the $e_{s \cdot I}$ are distinct and linearly independent so we have $\mu_s = 0 $ for all $s$.

I don't see how I'd solve the case $k > n$.

Maybe I can consider $I = (i_1,...,i_k)$ with $1 \leq i_1,...,i_k \leq n$ and look at

$$ \sum_{s} \mu_s e_{s\cdot I} = 0$$

and group terms $\mu_s e_{s \cdot I}$ and $\mu_{s'}e_{s' \cdot I}$ together whenever $s\cdot I = s' \cdot I$. This would yield a linear system of equations for the $\mu_s$'s and doing this for each $I$ would yield even more equations. This seems like a very messy approach though.

Comment: The claim is false if $k>n$, so you aren't missing anything.